# render another page after toastr notification in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, notifications, toastr

i am trying to render navigate another page after toastr notification disappear.

```
  showToasterWarning(){
    this.notifyService.showWarning("No Data Found for this Date!", "");
    
}
```

notifyService is a service for toastr.

In my code :

```
if(array == []){
this.showToasterWarning();
}
```

After notification disappear that mean after 4 or 5 second i want to to navigate another page using:

```
this.router.navigate(..........);
```

Only after toastr disappear i want to go to another page.

Any option in ngx-toastr to do whatever after notification disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please try this!

```
this.toastr.info('No Data Found for this Date!')
      .onHidden 
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('......'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Ngx-toast package provide us an observable when toastr hide.

After shown toastr, you can get its instance and use "onHidden" property.

```
    const toast = this.toastr.success('Hello!');
    toast.onHidden.subscribe(() => {
     console.log('Toast hidden');
     this.router.navigate(....)
    });
```

I made an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgk6qm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)